# Synthesizing a counter with an asynchronous edge-triggered reset

Tags: verilog, fpga

I want to synthesize a clock counter with an asynchronous edge-triggered reset: the counter increments on every `clk` rising edge, and resets to `0` on the rising edge of a `rst` signal.

**The counter reset to `0` must be edge-triggered since  the `rst` signal may stay high indefinitely.**

Here's what I have:

```
module clk_counter(input clk, input rst, output reg [7:0] count);

always @ (posedge rst) begin
    count <= 0;
end

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if(count < 255) begin
        count <= count + 1;
    end
end

endmodule
```

I'm having trouble synthesizing the implementation since `count` is "*connected to multiple drivers*" according to the error message my synthesizer spits out. I suspect this is due to a race condition in the design: the value of `count` is uncertain if both `rst` and `clk` rise at the same time.

I believe the race condition can be solved if there is a way to prioritize the edge-triggered reset operation to occur before the typical counter increments.

Is there a way to prioritize between two edge-triggered operations?

Comment: @toolic The `rst` signal is asynchronous to the `clk` signal.

Comment: If you expect rst to be valid during normal operation, it should be synchronous to clk. Otherwise, you can have issues with metastability (asynchronous removal/recovery) and break your circuit. It should be easy to resynchronize the rst signal to clk, as long as it is long enough.

Comment: @Vilhelm Gray, You expect the `count` to be sensitive to 2 edges. It's not synthesizable and this is not related to your target FPGA, because there is no hardware to implement it.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Is there a minimum duration of the `rst` high time, for example always 3 `clk`?

Comment: @MortenZilmer `rst` and `clk` are completely independent of each other. Forgive me for the poor naming as well since the `clk` signal does not necessarily have a set frequency. Imagine the system as such: Alice is in a isolated room pressing a button randomly (high signal when pressed, low signal when depressed) which feeds the `clk` input, while Bob is in another isolated room pressing another button randomly which feeds the `rst` signal -- both Alice and Bob can hold down their respective buttons for as long as they feel like at any given moment.

Comment: @MortenZilmer What did you have in mind If there was a minimum duration for the `rst` high time?

Comment: Asynchronous resets must assert a 'Minimum Reset Time' otherwise it won't work in every case. Normally, this time is at least 1 period of the destination clock domain. If the reset time is shorter, you must use a clock-domain-crossing circuit that synchronizes a strobe signal from one domain to another. The latter solution allows you to use synchronous reset for your counter.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: To implement this in FPGA with the generally available elements, the standard way is to use an ordinary clock for the counter flip-flop clock, and then synchronize `rst(Bob)` and `clk(Alice)` to the ordinary clock with double level flip-flops.  The synchronized `rst(Bob)` and `clk(Alice)` are then in the ordinary clock domain, and you can make a simple 0 to 1 detection for these, and make ordinary synchronous design, which works nicely with tools and FPGA.  Duration of `rst(Bob)` and `clk(Alice)` pulse must be at least 2 ordinary clock cycles for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Connected to multiple drivers" error is not a race condition - values cannot be assigned to the same net in multiple always blocks. Additionally, remember that HDL is not executed sequentially - placing an assignment earlier in a file won't give it any higher priority.

Instead, you'll need multiple sensitivities for your always block. Try this:

```
reg rst_prev;

always @(posedge clk)
     rst_prev <= rst;

always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
    if (rst)
    begin
        if (!rst_prev)
            count <= 0;
    end
    else begin
        if (count < 255)
            count <= count + 1;
    end
end
```

The main difference between this and the solution proposed by others is that as desired, it will only trigger on the edge of rst, since rst_prev will be 0, and rst will contain 1. However, this design is more sensitive to timing constraints (and more likely to have setup/hold violations) than the simpler designs.

Comment: VilhelmGray wrote in a comment that `rst` is **asynchronous** to `clk`, so this suggestion won't work, since `rst` and derived `rst_prev` are used on posedge of `clk`.

Comment: Although this solution does work in the sense that the reset operation occurs after a rising edge of `rst`, Morten Zilmer is right: if the `rst` signal toggles back and forth in the time between two `clk` rising edges, the reset operation may be missed.

Comment: I disagree. Yes, `rst` is asynchronous, but `rst_prev` will be. Also, I did attempt to mention that the design will be more dangerous, since there is a non-zero possibility for setup/hold violations if rst were to change close to a posedge of the clk. Buffering/Synchronizing rst would help. It's a tradeoff between detecting *only* the edge of `rst`, or having some chance of timing errors.

Comment: @VilhelmGray fair point - I'm not sure how one would capture that behaviour then.

Comment: @wilcroft When I attempt to synthesize your code, I get the following error message pointed at the `count < 255` if-statement: "*Assignment under multiple single edges is not supported for synthesis*." Do you know if this error is due simply to a physical limitation of my target FPGA, or is there an inherent synthesis issue in the code sample you supplied?

Comment: @Wilcroft: If `rst` is to be synchronized to a `rst_prev` in the `clk` domain, then it should at least be synchronized with two levels of flip-flops to avoid meta stability on `rst_prev`.

Comment: @VilhelmGray - Hmm.. I use Quartus II, and it doesn't have any issues with having multiple edges in the sensitivity list. I did have to make one change though: `if (rst && ~rst_prev)` became `if (rst) if (!rst_prev)` for synthesis to pass. See my edit above.

Comment: @MortenZilmer - to eliminate metastability, agreed; If you're doing that, it might be better to sync rst and be done with it. It's probably safer in the long run anyways, TBH - provided that the delay from rst to a sync'd rst wasn't detrimental to the design.

Comment: @wilcroft I believe the issue is with my target FPGA (Spartan 6 LX9); interestingly, your updated code now synthesizes for me - albeit with some warnings specific to my target FPGA.

Comment: @VilhelmGray - Probably because result of the same problem, just manifesting slightly differently - the synthesis tool detecting signals from different domains in the same if-block clause.

Comment: This proposed answer has metastability issues. If it even synthesizes. It should not be used.
The most fundamental error is in the question: A flip-flop with completely independent clk and rst is a fundamental design violation. It cannot be reliably done. @VilhelmGray you must rethink your approach so that you one way or another make at least the deassertion of rst sychronous to clk.